# 05 Honda Civic Lx

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

I've replaced my Radiator, Thermostat, and Water Pump.. and my car is still overheating.. they've told me to try my heater to cool it down every now and then but half of the time it works other times I'm having to pull over and wait it out.. no leaks hoses are new as well

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely it's a blown head gasket on the D17A1 engine in the car ... I went through it with an '03 LX. As long as I kept the radiator COMPLETELY full, it did just fine, but it eventually would burn some of the coolant, create enough space in the cooling system, and then overheat.